# Manipulate Wordpress Menu href attribute on custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom template in which i am calling `wp_nav_menu` function like below.

```
<?php
  $defaults = array(
  'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
  'menu' => '',
  'container' => 'nav',
  'container_class' => 'main-nav',
  'container_id' => '',
  'menu_class' => 'nav',
  'menu_id' => 'sub-nav',
  'echo' => true,
  'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
  'before' => '',
  'after' => '',
  'link_before' => '',
  'link_after' => '',
  'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'depth' => 0,
  'walker' => new Nav_Walker_Nav_Menu()
);
  wp_nav_menu($defaults);
```

The output i am receiving is like

```
<a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
```

When hoveing over the link i get the following url:

```
http://localhost/mysite/cart/#about
```

I want to remove `cart/` from this url so that i will get the url

```
http://localhost/mysite/#about
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dashboard, if you put `#about` as the link destination, it will create the link like you have which will take you as an anchor link to `#about` on any page it's displayed on (cart, whatever). If you want the link to be `http://localhost/mysite/#about`, you need to enter that full url in the menu link in the dashboard.

Just remember to change it when you take the site live.

Comment: Actually my other pages except the cart one are on single page. Thats why i have put only #about as menu link. Where as the cart page is totally other tempate. I tried the way you suggest. But it is not working. I need a way to manipulate the menu via code. because on both templates i have the same menu.

Comment: You can create a custom walker, but that's probably overkill. You can replace the URL with jQuery, or what I would suggest - create another menu for the cart using the full URLs as I stated, and show that menu on the cart page template. You can test for this in header.php (or wherever your menu is) and show one menu or the other. You would create the menu location in your functions.php file, and then call that menu (by theme_location) in your header for the cart page.

Comment: I inspect element and change the url to full path in href attribute. It is not going back. If i remove hash sign then it is working.

Comment: On your cart page, you'll also need to remove whatever smooth scrolling script is capturing the click. Right now, the menu on the cart is stopping the click, adding a class "selected" to the link, and looking for an id on the page. You need to remove that behavior so the click can bubble through and take the visitor to the main page #about section.